# Maven/Gradle set environment variable for compilation?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, annotation-processing

I developed an annotation processor that would optionally require the `artifactId` of the project to generate a file. I am using an environment variable (`GRAPHDEP_USAGE`) to get the value.

I can set the environment variable from shell before launching Maven/Gradle, but I would like the build tool to set the environment variable for me before the compilation instead:

- For **Maven**, inside the `pom.xml` i would like to populate the environment variable `GRAPHDEP_PROJECT` with the content of `${artifactId}`, before launching the `compile` goal.
- For **Gradle**, inside the `build.gradle` i would like to populate the environment variable `GRAPHDEP_PROJECT` with the content of `project.name`, before launching the task `compileJava`.

I tried a few options without success. Any idea how i can do that?

Comment: If you write a Maven plugin, you get the artifactId for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly answering the question, but actually answering the question behind which was how to pass arguments to annotation processors.

---

Compiler arguments can be specified with `-A` flag.

In **Gradle**:

```
compileJava.options.compilerArgs += "-Agraphdep.project=${project.name}"
```

In **Maven**:

```
<compilerArgs>
  <arg>-Agraphdep.project=${project.artifactId}</arg>
</compilerArgs>
```

Then from within an implementation of `AbstractProcessor` it is possible to retrieve the arguments using:

```
processingEnv.getOptions().get("widget");
```

The options supported must be declared by the processor, either by using the annotation `@SupportedOptions({"widget"})` or by overriding the method `public Set<String> getSupportedOptions()`.